# Add data into a dataframe based on whether ID exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes, `data` and `import_df` (see below). what I would like to do is add anther column to `data` and populate it with the `"mass"` column from `import_df` if the `Item ID` matches. I would like to name this new column a specific string which is known/generated.

`data`

```
ItemID Name
1276   Part 1
1382   Part 2
.      .
.      .
.      .
```

`import_df`

```
ItemID Name
1276   15
1672   32
1662   90
1382   32
.      .
.      .
.      .
```

End goal would be:
`data`

```
ItemID Name    date variable (mass)
1276   Part 1  15
1382   Part 2  32
.      .
.      .
.      .
```

I think I could manage using a `for` loop that cycles through each row of both data frames but I think there must be a better way.

Comment: [Pandas merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you need to join two dataframes on a common column. Do this:

```
data = data.merge(import_df, on="ItemID")
```